# how to use usestate with node.js backend and react frontend

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

i use node.js in my HTML file using  tag now how do i use useState with it
I tried:

```
const {useState} = React
```

Here is my code

```
const {useState} = React;
function App(){
const {text, setText} = useState("Hello world")
console.log(text);
function handleClick(){
  setText("Hello universe")
}

return <h1 onClick={handleClick}> {text} </h1>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Are you using create react app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial state is set up slightly wrong

change

```
const {text, setText} = useState("Hello world")
```

to this

```
const [text, setText] = useState("Hello world")
```